# Различие require и include

Tags: require, include, php

Объясните, пожалуйста, чем отличается require от include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тем что require используется когда файл жизненно необходим программе - он подключится при обработке страницы, а include - во время интерпритации. И если файл не будет найден - fatal error, а при include просто ошибка или Warning, не помню точно.

Comment: @stck, а что их них быстрее? include или require?

Comment: @ModaL, как заметил товарищ @thunder, "are identical in every way", т.е. скорость работы одинакова:)

Comment: @stck, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> `require()` and `include()`  are identical in every way except how they handle failure. `include()` produces a Warning while `require()` results in a `Fatal Error`.
>
> `require` идентично `include` за исключением того, что при ошибке оно также выдаст фатальную ошибку уровня `E_COMPILE_ERROR`. Другими словами, она остановит выполнение скрипта, тогда как `include` только выдала бы предупреждение `E_WARNING`, которое позволило бы скрипту продолжить выполнение.

Источник: [php.net manual](http://il.php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php)